# Полноценный динамический массив Qt/C++

Tags: c++, qt

Мне нужна структура данных, аналогичная одномерному массиву: ключ - `int`, значение - произвольное, количество элементов - произвольное (не задаваемое при объявлении). В этой структуре данных должна быть возможность удалять элементы **со сдвигом индекса** и возможность заполнять данные **не по порядку** (например сначала в индекс 1, а потом в 0). Уже посмотрел `QList` - нельзя заполнять данные не по порядку и `QHash` - нет сдвига индекса при удалении элемента.

Подскажите как называется то, что мне нужно, заранее благодарен.

Comment: ¿Что еще за сдвиг индекса? ¿Вот например после вставки по индексам 3 и 7, и последующего удаления по индексу 3, где должно оказаться число, записанное ранее по индексу 7?

Comment: В моем понимании сдвиг индекса это так: например есть массив {3, 5, 7} индекс 0 - значение 3, индекс 1 - значение 5, индекс 2 - значение 7. Мы удаляем элемент с индексом 1 (значение 5) и тогда у значения 7 индекс меняется с 2 на 1.

Comment: `QList` можно создать сразу с заданным размером. Тогда его можно заполнять не по порядку.

Comment: QVector и std::vector нельзя заполнять не по порядку.

Comment: `vector` можно заполнять не по порядку. Просто задайте ему размер. Не хватает размера? Сделайте resize.

Comment: Я думаю, что Вам должен подойти QMap, у него есть методы для итерации по элементам. Но такие же методы есть и у QHash - почему он не подошел?